# How To Code Subview(s) Image Indicators Collapsing to the Right in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

Given iOS 6.0+:

- I have 3 image indicators A, B, C who always appear in this order from left to right. They cannot repeat. No A A A.
- Any of A, B, C can be on or off (show or not show)
- When a letter is not showing, the others collapse to the right; example A C

What is the most straight forward approach to this? Create about 6 images and swap them in based on whether A, B, or C are on?

See image for example.[image]

I have reviewed Apple's [A Closer Look at Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do 3 images for A, B & C. Put 3 hidden image views. Unhide and put the right image as needed.

- ex1: all visible, A in i1, B in i2, C in i3
- ex2: only i3 visible with B image.

Comment: Just swap in the right image into stationary subviews and show as needed? Good idea. It would be neat if I could just show the things and they auto fall to the right as needed. Seemed like an autolayout opportunity or something.

Comment: Yes it may help, but I haven't used it a lot because I needed compatibility for older iOS. What you can do to make it "fall" is loop from C to A, the first visible is put in a imageView with the frame that's most right, second visible on it's left etc etc. But you need to set the frame in code.